# Problems Running Yarn In Vim Autocommand

Tags: vim, zsh, yarnpkg

I am using vim as my IDE and I have started to work on my very first Vue project, so I have added the following to my .vimrc:

```
" Automagically run yarn compiler when saving vue files
augroup vimrc
      autocmd!
      au BufWritePost *.vue term ++close ++rows=12 yarn run build
augroup END
```

It works pretty well so far, I have it on ++close because 99% of the time everything compiles great and I see that it says "Done" in the terminal window and then a second later it closes.

The problem comes when there's an error, in which case the terminal window closes *instantly* if yarn reports an error, and since it was a terminal window, the buffer doesn't stay in memory. I therefore can't go back and see what the error was.

Ok, no big deal... I tried getting around it by just opening up another terminal in tmux and running the yarn command there only in the cases that there are errors, but I found an interesting "bug" in my system there...

If I create a variable but don't use it, some linting is going on which causes yarn to fail, but *ONLY* when running it from an autocmd.

I can run the following in command mode:

```
:term ++close ++rows=12 yarn run build
```

or

```
:term ++rows=12 yarn run build
```

or I can run

```
$ yarn run build
```

in a separate terminal, and in all of those cases, the yarn command will succeed, because it doesn't care about my unused variable.

But if I run it as an autocommand in vim because I've saved App.vue, then the command fails and I have to take off the ++close in my autocmd because that's the only way for the window to stay open long enough for me to see what the error is, and it's "Variable x is declared but never used."

**Is the filename or any extra linting information passed to yarn if I run this as an autocmd?
If not, how/why does yarn care about my unused variable only when I run it as an autocmd?**

Also, for extra credit: is it possible for me to do one or more of the following?

1. Autoclose the terminal window only if the compile succeeded (leave it open if there were errors)
2. Leave a window reserved for compilation at the bottom of the screen open at all times, and have the autocmd be a function that creates that window if it doesn't already exist, and then runs the terminal in that window (preferably while hiding the window whenever it's not needed)
3. Keep the output of yarn in a buffer even after the window closes, so if I need to I can go back in and see what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an efficient approach *at all*.

Front-end projects usually include some kind of watcher that rebuilds your project *incrementally* whenever you change a watched file. There is no point whatsoever in involving your text editor, especially Vim, in that part of the process… or to rebuild the whole thing on every write.

If your project is a pure Vue.js project created via `$ vue create foobar`, then it comes with a built-in dev server that you are supposed to start in a separate terminal window, or tmux pane, or `:terminal` window in Vim, or wherever you want:

```
$ yarn serve
```

that will watch your changes and handle everything on its own. I prefer to do it in a separate terminal tab but, if you really like Vim's built-in terminal emulator, it's all just a:

```
:vert term yarn serve
```

away:

[image: :vert term yarn serve]

If it's a Nuxt.js project, then you should have a `dev` script in your `package.json`, that is to be used in the exact same manner:

```
:term yarn dev
```

[image: :term yarn dev]

If you use another "framework", read its documentation.

That is basically the gist of it.

---

On another note, `yarn` is only used as a dumb script runner, here. It doesn't compile, it doesn't know about errors, etc. It's whatever is executed by the `build` script in your `package.json` that does, so I would suggest you study the responsibilities of each piece of the system you are working with and the boundaries between those pieces if you really want to grok it.